# Single '#' in old C files

Tags: c

I started studying old C code (Unix v6) and I'm wondering what is the purpose of a single `#` in the beginning of the `.c` file. For example from https://github.com/lsahn-gh/unix-v6/blob/master/sys%2Fken%2Falloc.c

```
#
/*
 */

#include "../param.h"
#include "../systm.h"
#include "../filsys.h"
...
```

Comment: Answered at https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/18254/5096 (which is more appropriate for ancient code&history)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

From [Stephen Kitt](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/79/stephen-kitt)'s [answer on the Retrocomputing Stack Exchange](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/18253/where-is-the-ancient-preprocessor/18254#18254):

> Dennis M. Ritchie’s [*The Development of the C Language*](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html) paper gives this context:
>
> > [...] The preprocessor was originally considered an optional adjunct to the
> > language itself. Indeed, for some years, it was not even invoked
> > unless the source program contained a special signal at its beginning.
>
> [...] The “special signal at its beginning” is `#` as the very first character.

Comment: Oh, so it's not a reduced version of [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)), as I thought. Today I've learned.

Answer (score 13):

It is a no-op. From [one of the standards](https://web.archive.org/web/20161223125339/http://flash-gordon.me.uk/ansi.c.txt) (the definition has not changed):

> 3.8.7 Null directive
>
> Semantics
>
> A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> ```
>     #  new-line
> ```
>
> has no effect.

As for the purpose, it's been asked before, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10020922/whats-the-point-of-the-c-preprocessors-null-directive) for example. At the time it might have had something to do with readibility, since the line with # is visible only in the source, the preprocessor does not output anything at all. But that's just guessing, in practice it has been and still is a no-op.

Answer (score 3):

That declares the line to be a preprocessor directive, not unique to just old C code.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66548702/what-do-you-call-in-c-and-c

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor

https://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/